# Simple app to take username and password from the user

Tags: c#, beginner

I'm beginner at programming (I guess it's quite obvious)  and this is my small "app" I tried to make, that takes username and password from the user. Could you give me some advice on how can I improve it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace Login
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Initialization();
        }

        public static void Initialization()
        {
            int x = 0;
            int choice = 0;

            while (x < 2)
            {
                Console.Clear();

                Console.Write("Username: ");
                string username = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("\nPassword: ");
                string password = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine();

                string option1 = "Login";
                string option2 = "Exit";

                Console.WriteLine(option1 + "\n" + option2);

                while (x < 2)
                {
                    ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey();
                    if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.ResetColor();

                        Console.WriteLine("Username: {0}", username);
                        Console.WriteLine("\nPassword: {0}\n", password);

                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine(option1);

                        Console.ResetColor();
                        Console.WriteLine(option2);

                        choice = 1;
                    }
                    else if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.ResetColor();

                        Console.WriteLine("Username: {0}", username);
                        Console.WriteLine("\nPassword: {0}\n", password);

                        Console.ResetColor();
                        Console.WriteLine(option1);

                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine(option2);
                        choice = 2;

                    }

                    if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter && choice == 1)
                    {
                        if (Login(username, password) == true)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
                            x = 2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Wrong password!");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    else if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter && choice == 2)
                    {
                        Shutdown();
                    }
                }
            }


        }
        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            Console.ResetColor();
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        public static bool Login(string username, string password)
        {
            if(username == "asd" && password == "asd")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! For future reference: [Tips on how to write a good Code Review question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562)

Comment: You don't communicate up and down arrows for  the options

Answer (score 5):

Just a few things:

- Don't use `\n` as a literal, we use `Environment.NewLine` instead.
- Don't use "string concatenation" (`string + string`), instead use `string.Join`, `string.Format` or a `StringBuilder`. I.e.:

  > ```
  > Console.WriteLine(option1 + "\n" + option2);
  > ```

  Should be:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", option1, Environment.NewLine, option2);
  ```

  Just as well, you should, ideally, switch this to two `Console.WriteLine` statements:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(option1);
  Console.WriteLine(option2);
  ```
- A method should have on responsibility (SRP):

  ```
  public static bool Login(string username, string password)
  {
      if(username == "asd" && password == "asd")
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
          return true;
      }
      else
      {
          return false;
      }
  }
  ```

  The `Console.WriteLine` statement does not belong there, `Login` should simply return `true` or `false` in this case.

Comment: Whilst I agree about string concatenation in this specific case, I disagree with the blanket statement *Don't use "string concatenation"*. String concatenation with a few strings is more efficient than calling string.Format or using a StringBuilder, and depending on its use can be more or less legible than calling a method.